# Navigating file using helm

Tags: regex, emacs, emacs-helm

I am trying to set up a function using helm to navigate a beamer file following the suggestion at : "http://blog.jenkster.com/2013/10/a-tip-for-navigating-clojure-files-in-emacs.html". I tried:

```
(defun helm-beamer-headlines ()
  "Display headlines for the current Beamer file."
  (interactive)
  (helm-mode t)
  (helm :sources '(((name . "Beamer Headlines")
                    (volatile)
                    (headline "^\\s\|^\\f")))))
```

to show only the lines starting with \f and \s (corresponding to sectioning and frame commands), and while the regexp works with emacs regexp search and helm-occur, I get no matches with `M-x helm-beamer-headlines`.

A minimal file that I tried it on is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{Aa}
\frame{\frametitle{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}
}
\subsection{Ab}
\frame{\frametitle{}
\begin{align*}
\alpha&=\beta
\end{align*}
}
\section{B}
\subsection{Ba}
\frame{\frametitle{}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{abc.png}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You probably want `"^\\\\s.*\\|^\\\\f.*"` or at least **`"^\\\\s\\|^\\\\f"`** as your regexp.  See [`(elisp) Syntax for Strings`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html#Syntax-for-Strings) and [`(elisp) Regexp Backslash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash)
   about backslashes in Lisp.
2. I can't speak to just what you should use for Helm. But as an alternative, this is all you need if you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles):

   ```
   (defun foo ()
     "..."
     (interactive)
     (icicle-search (point-min) (point-max) "^\\\\s.*\\|^\\\\f.*" t))
   ```

Then `M-x foo TAB` in your beamer buffer.  Completion candidates are the lines you want. Navigate among them using `C-down` etc.  See the [doc for **Icicles** search](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) for more info.